# How to define an object with known and unknown property types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to define a TypeScript type with properties I know and properties I don't know.
It looks like this:

```js
type MetaType = {
    res?: HttpResponse;
    req?: HttpRequest;
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | string[]
}
// Error: Property 'res' of type 'HttpResponse' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string | number | boolean | string[]'.ts(2411)
```

So the idea is, if it has a property `res`, it must be a `HttpResponse` and if it has a property `req`, it must be a `HttpRequest`. The rest can be any string (except `res` and `req` as key with the defined type).

I also tried this:

```js
type MetaType = {
    res?: HttpResponse;
    req?: HttpRequest;
} & Record<string, string | number | boolean | string[]>;
// No error
```

I don't get any error on the type, but when I try to use it:

```js
const meta: MetaType = {
    message: "hello",
    count: 12,
    req,
    res,
};
// Error: 
Type '{ message: string; count: number; req: HttpRequest; res: HttpResponse; }' is not assignable to type 'MetaType'.
  Type '{ message: string; cpi,t: number; req: HttpRequest; res: HttpResponse; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | number | boolean | string[]>'.
    Property 'req' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'HttpRequest' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | string[]'.
        Type 'HttpRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 34 more
```

I also tried this, but without success as well:

```js
export type MetaType = {
    res?: HttpResponse;
    req?: HttpRequest;
    [key: Exclude<string, 'res' | 'req'>]: string | number | boolean | string[];
};
// Error: Property 'res' of type 'HttpResponse' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string | number | boolean | string[]'.ts(2411)
```

Is it something we can do with the current version of TypeScript? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not directly possible in TypeScript. There's a longstanding open feature request at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) you might want to give a  to.  In the meantime there are various workarounds with various benefits and drawbacks, described in the answer to the linked question.   Sorry not to have better news here.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz. I gave my  to the related issue on Github. Didn't think this use case wasn't handle by TS and didn't check on the repo.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The problem here seems to be that, when using indexed types, the values attached to indexed type have to cover all of the types used in type or interface declaration. That means that you could either do something like:

```js
type MetaType = {
    res?: HttpResponse;
    req?: HttpRequest;
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | string[] | HttpResponse | HttpRequest | undefined
}
```

Note that you have to add **undefined** as well, because you have optional fields which may be undefined.

As you are asking for an alternative I would decide on design level for something else beside trying to represent all of the possible fields which you do not know.

Why not just use a Map as additional property here, to store all of the things which are neither res nor req? For example:

```js
type MetaType = {
    res?: HttpResponse;
    req?: HttpRequest;
    others: Map<string, any> = new Map<string, any>();
}
```